# How to Double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate $$\int_0^1\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy\, dx$$

In my book said that use tangent function but.. I don`t know.. help me.
I want to know process of calculate this problem.

and one more question

f(x,y)=1, if x rational

f(x,y)=2y, if x irrational

then why f is not integrable? but iterated integral exists? over[0,1]x[0,1]

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1st Question:

$$ \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \arctan ( y/x ) $$

Hint for 2nd Question: Whats the issue with integrating a wild (discontinuous) function?

Comment: I want to know more specifically... because.. I have no enough time