# Help my homework: $\int_0^1\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate $$\int_0^1\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy\, dx$$

In my book said that use tangent function but I don`t know how to evaluate it. Please help me.
I want to know the process of evaluating this integral.

One more question

$f(x,y)=1$, if $x$ rational

$f(x,y)=2y$, if $x$ irrational

then why is $f(x,y)$ not integrable but the iterated integral exists over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$? Thank you.

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions at once, and please use proper English and LaTeX.

Comment: @user111187 I think we can understand about the English part since not all users here use English as the primary language in their country, included me. :)

Comment: @user142512 you can ask your second question as a separate question. Then it would be clearer to answer.

Comment: Not sure if this is same person, but this was just posted. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787270/how-to-double-integrals/787338#787338

Comment: For your second question, the set of discontinuities of $f(x,y)$ has positive measure. So it is not even Lebesgue measurable. Note that it is integrable in the form $dy\; dx$ since $\int_{[0,1]} 1 = \int_{[0,1]} 2y = 1$. We have that the lower and upper integral of the inner part (with respect to $dy$) is $1$. Hence, the inner integral is $1$ and so it works. Note that integrating $dx\; dy$ does not exist for then $f(x,y)$ would be integrable by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: @user111187 You are always helpful to me towards my problems and I thank you.  However, it is quite rude to comment to the OP to use proper English.  English is not everybody's first language as Tunk-Fey said.  Also if you want to be serious about using proper English, you should not use contractions (ex: don't) when making your point.  Rather you can say "do not ask multiple questions.."

Comment: see here it is the first exercise http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=27147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we evaluate
$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy.
$$
Let $y=x\tan\theta$, then $dy=x\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy&=\int_{y=0}^1\frac{x^2-x^2\tan^2\theta}{(x^2+x^2\tan^2\theta)^2}\cdot x\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\frac1x\int_{y=0}^1\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{\sec^4\theta}\cdot \sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\frac1x\int_{y=0}^1\left(1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\right)\cdot \cos^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\frac1x\int_{y=0}^1\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)\ d\theta\\
&=\frac1x\int_{y=0}^1 \cos2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\left.\frac1{2x} \sin2\theta\ \right|_{y=0}^1\\
&=\left.\frac1{x} \sin\theta\ \cos\theta\ \right|_{y=0}^1\\
&=\left.\frac1{x}\cdot\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ \right|_{y=0}^1\\
&=\left.\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\ \right|_{y=0}^1\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2+1}.
\end{align}
$$
Now
$$
\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy\ dx=\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx.
$$
Let $x=\tan\theta$, then $dx=\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$ and $0<x<1$ is corresponding to $0<\theta<\dfrac\pi4$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{1}{\tan^2\theta+1}\cdot\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}\cdot\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ d\theta\\
&=\frac\pi4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What happens if you change the order of integration?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I know where is your question heading to, but I just try to help the OP by integrating as the order of integration in the OP. Thanks for your 'warning'. :)

Comment: But the OP indicates that he already knows that the iterated integral exists. The issue is, why is the function not integrable.

Comment: @MarkMcClure OK, my bad then. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start with

$$\int\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+C$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: If you continue down this path, you'll get $\pi/4$. If you change the order of integration, you'll get $-\pi/4$. Symmetry suggests the answer is zero. If you split the square into two triangles along the line $y=x$, you'll see that the integral is in fact divergent.

Comment: Looking more closely at his question - you perhaps knew this!